# von Neumann Algebras and measures

Tags: measure-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I read that any abelian von Neumann algebra is isomorphic to $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ for some $X$ and $\mu$. This seems to be reasons, to consider any von Neumann Algebra as non-commutative measurable space. Could someone explain to me why? And if I look at Type $II_1$ factors, is the trace some sort of measure? Thank you

Comment: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/261ynotes/lecture13.pdf

Comment: Thank you. But if I take any von Neumann Algebra, why can consider it a non-ablien measurable space?

Comment: Your question seems to duplicate this one:

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/137609/von-neumann-algebras-and-measurable-spaces?lq=1